# Multiprocessing in Python: keep only the first result returned

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on project involving a long, probabilistic subroutine. The goal is finding a number n. I am trying to develop a multiprocessing way of doing it. Basically, the code looks like this:

```
def f(x):
    if (random. random()<0.1):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def search():
    while True:
        candidate = random.randint()
        if(f(candidate)):
            return candidate
        else:
            continue


print(search())
```

And I would like to run several instances of the function `search()` (which are completely independent) in multiple processes, and then

**keep only the result of the first instance of `f()` which terminates the execution**.

All tutorials I have seen yet emphasize on creating a process `p` and then making it wait for the other computations to finish using `p.join()`, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Does anyone have a solution to this (simple) problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of `multiprocessing.Queue` and pass it to subprocesses. When a subprocess finds a result, it should put it into the queue. The main process should read the result from the queue and then terminate all the subprocesses.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. Even though I have not been able to implement this modification the program yet because I do not fully understand the behavior of `Queue`, this looks like the solution.